# Joomla 1.7 - Failed login gets 500 error

Tags: joomla, joomla1.7

When a user logs in to the front end incorrectly, they get a 500 error page.

In previous installations, the page just refreshes. Ideally, I'd like an error message displayed but this isn't happening either (even on previous installations). I assumed that this was achieved by:

```
<jdoc:include type="message" />
```

Paths to log/tmp files are correct. Permissions seem OK. Any ideas?

Thanks,

Andy

Comment: That's for 1.5 but might be helpful: http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=404&t=258344

Comment: Thanks @alfasin. The login form is configured fine, but I want some sort of 'login failed' or 'incorrect username/password' feedback rather than a 500 error page. Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have the 1.7 installed so I can't help. but what I would do, is try to `grep` the 'login failed' msg, find the file that displays it and change it. quick & dirty...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it was something with the logs dir. Change the permissions and try again.
Update the configuration file

update the full URL of temp and log folder

Comment: Thanks. From configuration.php, public $log_path = '/logs'; public $tmp_path = '/tmp'; - both exist in joomla root directory. Sorry about comment formatting. No idea how to get new line (enter submits comment)